# MongoDB: Disable user --auth, but keep cluster auth

Tags: mongodb, authentication, pymongo, replication, systemd

I am a pre-existing MongoDB (5.0) replica set that I would like to disable user auth for, but *keep cluster auth* on.

What I did was:

1. `sudo systemctl stop mongod.service` - stop the service
2. `sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` -
   edit the line:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip localhost,<my ip> --replSet mongodb --auth --clusterAuthMode=keyFile --keyFile=/etc/mongodb/keyFile`

to

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip localhost,<my ip> --replSet mongodb --clusterAuthMode=keyFile --keyFile=/etc/mongodb/keyFile`

3. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` - reload service
4. `sudo systemctl start mongod.service` - start service

Then on a separate machine, I went to verify my auth changes.

```
$ pip3 install pymongo==3.12.1
$ python3

from pymongo import MongoClient
PORT=27017
ADDR=<my ip>
connection = ADDR + ":" + str(PORT)
client = MongoClient(connection, replicaset="mongodb")
client.admin.command("replSetGetStatus")
```

which reports `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command usersInfo requires authentication`.

Interestingly enough when I redo steps 1-4. but change 2. to `ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip localhost,<my ip> --replSet mongodb`. I am able to re-run the above experiment without issue.

So here are my questions:

1. I thought the flags `clusterAuthMode=keyFile --keyFile=/etc/mongodb/keyFile` were only for replicas in the cluster authenticating others. Is that true?
2. If 1. is correct then why can I not access my cluster from outside the cluster with these fields?
3. Is there a better way to verify auth? I saw some other posts on here that used a shell script but did not work for me.

Comment: That's not possible, see [security.keyFile](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-security.keyFile): *`keyFile` implies `security.authorization`.* or [Internal/Membership Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/#std-label-inter-process-auth): *Enabling internal authentication also enables client authorization.*

Answer (score 0):

As @Wernfried Domscheit commented:

- the [security.keyFile](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-security.keyFile): `keyFile` implies `security.authorization`. or [Internal/Membership Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/#std-label-inter-process-auth): Enabling internal authentication also enables client authorization

So essentially you cannot have cluster auth without user auth